# Gsutil gives 401 error despite fresh install and proper credentials

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

I have been using `gsutil` with Google cloud for almost a year through my organization with no issues.  This morning, when I try to use any `gsutil` command, I get the following error:

```
401 Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.list access to bucket <my-bucket>.
```

What I have tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling `gcloud` via `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash` as well as `pip install -U gcloud gsutil`.
- I have deleted my `.boto` file before and after reinstalling.
- I have tried installing inside and outside of an anaconda environment.  Note that both configurations were working without issue previously
- Before reinstalling, I remove any references to `gcloud` from `~/.bash_profile`

Output of `gsutil version -l`:

```
gsutil version: 4.22
checksum: 2434a37a663d09ae21d1644f64ce60ca (OK)
boto version: 2.42.0
python version: 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17) [GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)]
OS: Darwin 15.6.0
multiprocessing available: True
using cloud sdk: True
config path: /Users/<username>/.boto
gsutil path: /Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/gsutil
compiled crcmod: True
installed via package manager: False
editable install: False
```

Output of `gcloud info`

```
Google Cloud SDK [146.0.0]

Platform: [Mac OS X, x86_64]
Python Version: [2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:43:17)  [GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)]]
Python Location: [/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source/bin/python2]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  core: [2017.02.28]
  core-nix: [2016.11.07]
  gcloud-deps: [2017.02.28]
  gcloud: []
  gsutil-nix: [4.18]
  gsutil: [4.22]
  bq: [2.0.24]
  gcloud-deps-darwin-x86_64: [2017.02.21]
  bq-nix: [2.0.24]
System PATH: [/Users/<username>/anaconda/envs/tensorflow_source/bin:/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Users/<username>/anaconda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]
Kubectl on PATH: [False]

Installation Properties: [/Users/<username>/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/Users/<username>/.config/gcloud]
Active Configuration Name: [jared]
Active Configuration Path: [/Users/<username>/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_jared]

Account: [<email>]
Project: [<project-name>]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    project: [<project-name>]
    account: [<email>]
    disable_usage_reporting: [False]
  [compute]
    region: [us-east1]
    zone: [us-east1-c]

Logs Directory: [/Users/<username>/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/Users/<username>/.config/gcloud/logs/2017.03.08/14.00.35.867536.log]
```

Using `gsutil` from a compute instance after running `gcloud auth login` and using my personal credentials is also working so I know it is not an issue with my account.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Another observation:  The file `~/.boto` is blank and there is another file with path `~/.config/gcloud/legacy_credentials/<email>/.boto` that just has my credentials Oauth token.

Comment: Try `gcloud auth application-default login`

Comment: No change after running that.  See edit though, maybe that could be it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I got it working, not sure if this answer will apply to anyone else but I will post what I did just in case.

This morning I deleted all files related to google cloud (`rm -rf ~/google-cloud-sdk && rm -rf ~/.config && rm ~/.boto`).  For me the `~/.config` folder only had a google cloud folder inside but you might want to check to make sure there isn't anything else before just deleting it.

Then I restarted my computer and reinstalled gcloud via `curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash` and closed and reopened the terminal instead of running `exec -l $SHELL` but I think that does the same thing.  After running `gcloud init` everything worked fine.

I am still not sure what happened here.